# Fire store in python filling fields with random data

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question about python and firestore, I have conected python to fire store and I can add data however when I try to fill in a field in my database using a **Varible** all I get in the firebase console is a random string.

---

My code

```
import urllib
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
link = "example.com/test1"
f = urllib.urlopen(link)
uw = f.read()
linky = "Example.com/test.txt"
fa = urllib.urlopen(linky)
uname = fa.read()
print(uname)
unname=uname
# Use a service account
uname="hello"
cred = credentials.Certificate('key.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
#uw="hello"
db = firestore.client()
doc_ref = db.collection(u'treasure').document(uw)
doc_ref.set({
    u'found_by': uname
    #u'last': u'Lovelace',
    #u'born': 1815
})
#print(uuname)
print(uname)
```

**Here is my firebase console**
[Sorry, I don't have the needed reputation to embed an image but here is the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Fgo.png)

---

**note**

---

I am trying to load the data to put into the database from a server however I have verified this is not the issue. the first one of these url ib request is getting a name of the document however this works well but the second one is where I get the field data **but** the problem is **not** loading it off a server
**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is being [base64-encoded](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode).

```
>>> s = 'aGVsbG8='
>>> base64.b64decode(s)
b'hello'
```

I don't use Firebase/Firestore but if the data is being automatically base64-encoded on write then most likely it will be automatically decoded when read.

If you need to manually decode it, note that `base64.b64decode` returns `bytes`, so you need to call .decode() on the bytes to get a `str`.

This comment on [github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/1847#issuecomment-224954292) suggests that adding the `u` prefix to string literals will make Firestore encode as UTF-8 instead of base64.

So in your example:

```
uname = u'Hello'
```